# How can I deploy an app using Identity Model to Production on Azure?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-sql-database

I'm pretty new to MVC.  I'd like to deploy the default sample web app to Azure with a basic Identity Model installed so that I can confirm basic user authentication is working in production.  I can't seem to get it working.

I am using Visual Studio 2015 RC.  I launch a new MVC web application project.  IdentityModels.cs is installed by default.  If I connect to LocalDB, it runs great.  If I connect to an Azure SQL DB instead, it runs great.  I am able to register and then log in with the credentials I've created.  The database updates as expected either locally or on my Azure SQL instance.

The problem is when I deploy to production.  I make no changes to the code whatsoever, and Publish via Web Deploy.  When running the same code from an Azure website, I try to submit user info on the Registration page and I get a 500 error: Failed to load resource.

It seems that my Azure website cannot connect to the Azure SQL DB, even though I verified that it could connect just before I used Web Deploy.  Can anyone help me figure out why?

Comment: When you publish to Azure is your connectionstring pointed at the Azure Sql Db? or localdb? I don't think localdb is supported on azure websites, so just confirming. Whats the exact error message? Are you getting a stack trace with the error?

Comment: I'm pointing at the Azure Sql Db when using Web Deploy.  I believe you're correct that a localdb connection wouldn't work from the cloud.  No stack trace.  The page header of the Login page loads successfully, but the body says "{Layout = null;} Error. An error occurred while processing your request." And the browser throws 500 on Line 1 of the html: "500 error: failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to allow `Windows Azure Services` for your Azure DB through managing the allowed IP addresses, because your DB is initially inaccessible, except from an IP range that you specify.

[image]